# what is the cause of this java exception 'java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException?'

Tags: java, exception, serial-port

I used comm.jar in my project to read data from com port but when I make listen and wait any data from com port this exception ......

```
Exception in thread "Win32SerialPort Notification thread" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at getsmsf1.IncomingSms.<init>(IncomingSms.java:160)
        at getsmsf1.Sms.lineReceived(Sms.java:563)
        at getsmsf1.Sms.serialEvent(Sms.java:463)
        at com.sun.comm.Win32SerialPort.sendDataAvailEvent(Win32SerialPort.java:649)
        at com.sun.comm.NotificationThread.run(Win32SerialPort.java:878)
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 65533
        at getsmsf1.PduCodec.<clinit>(PduCodec.java:299)
        ... 5 more
```

Comment: I am having this same issue. Please did you eventually resolve problem?

Comment: Take another look. That's not the exception, nor the message: it is obviously a thread title. The actual exception is 'Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 65533'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 65533
```

seems root cause. It seems you are trying for index 65533 which is out of range.

```
Win32SerialPort Notification thread
```

is just thread name where this exception occured.